# How can I call some code after a property on my state object has been defined?

Tags: reactjs

I have a component, which has a prop passed to it.

It seems that this prop is `undefined` at the point `componentDidMount()` is called.

Here's my component:

```
export class BookInventoryDetail extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            book_inventories: []
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        console.log(this.props) // the prop book_id is undefined.
        Book.fetchInventories(this.props.book_id).then(book_inventories => {
            this.setState({book_inventories})
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>

            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Am I doing this correctly, or is book_id simply not defined when I think it should be in the parent?

Either I'm doing something wrong in this component, or the issue exists in the parent component, and the prop isn't being set when I think it is.

Comment: Seems to be issue in your parent component , since props are not defined no way you can proceed further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All props should be already available in `componentDidMount` lifecycle method. I assume you sholud check book_id prop in parent component. Is everything ok there? May be you do not pass this value.

Comment: Yeah, seems that's the issue, lol. The whole asynchronousness of JavaScript basically.